# Adding a list of values to a Printer class

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, class

In this code if the user types >>> **create 5**

it will create 5 different Printer objects

when the user types >>> **add 1 2 3 4 5**

the program should add 1 page to the first Printer object

then add 2 pages to the second Printer object

and so on...

when the user types >>> **add 1 2 3 4 5 6**

or when the user types >>> **add 1 2 3**

it should check for empty Printer objects (Printer.isEmpty() instances)

then add the value to those empty printers until theres no more empty printers then enqueue the rest of to jobs.

Currently my output is:

```
printSimulation()
create 5
add 1 2 3
status
Printer: 0 Pages to print: 1 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 1 Pages to print: 2 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 2 Pages to print: 3 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 3 Pages to print: 0 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 4 Pages to print: 0 Total pages printed: 0
add 1 2 3 4 5
status
Printer: 0 Pages to print: 2 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 1 Pages to print: 4 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 2 Pages to print: 6 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 3 Pages to print: 4 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 4 Pages to print: 5 Total pages printed: 0
add 1 2 3 4 5 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Python Shell, prompt 2, line 1
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
    if created[i].isEmpty():
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

*This program is not at all checking for empty Printers and then enqueueing if there is no empty printers*

**This is my code below:**

```
class Queue:
    class Job:
        def __init__(self, element, _next):
            self._element = element
            self._next = _next
            
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._front = None
        self._rear = None
        self._size = 0
    def __str__(self):
        pass
    def enqueue(self, n):
        if self.isEmpty():
            self._front = self.Job(n, None) #setting the front value
            self._rear = self._front #value on the end is now the value in the previous front
            self._size += 1 #adds 1 to size
            return
        self._rear._next = self.Job(n, None) #rear value is None
        self._rear = self._rear._next #sets the latter value
        self._size += 1
        return 
    
    def dequeue(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise EmptyError('Queue is empty. Cannot dequeue.')
        dequeued = self._front._element #our popped/dequeued element
        self._front = self._front._next #new front is the next item 
        self._size -= 1 #subtract 1 from size
        if self.isEmpty():
            self._rear = None
        return dequeued
    
    def front(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise EmptyError('Queue is empty. Front element does not exist.')
        return self._front._element
    def __len__(self):
        return self._size
    
    def isEmpty(self):
      
        return self._size == 0

class Printer:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self._number = number
        self._pages = 0
        self._print = 0
        self._cycles = 0
        
    def add(self, n):
        self._pages += int(n)
        
    def status(self):
        return f'Printer: {self._number} Pages to print: {self._pages} Total pages printed: {self._print}'
    
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self._pages == 0
        
           
def printSimulation():
    jobs = Queue()
    amount = []
    created = []
    while True:
        command = str(input())
        
        if 'create' in command:
            val = command.split(' ')[1] #separation of command from value
            amount.append(val)
            
            for printers in range(int(val)):
                printers = Printer(printers)
                created.append(printers)
                
        if 'status' in command:
            for items in created:
                print(items.status())
               
        if 'add' in command:
            value = command.split(' ')
            value.remove(value[0])
            if len(created) == len(value):
                for i in range(len(created)):
                    created[i].add(value[i])
            if len(created) != len(value):
                for i in range(len(value)):
                    if created[i].isEmpty():
                        created[i].add(value[i])
                    else:
                        jobs.enqueue(int(value[i]))
```

Comment: What is ```Queue```

Comment: apologies a Queue is a linked list method

Comment: No problem, just mention it

Answer (score 1):

```py
            for i in created:
                
                if len(created) == len(value):
                    for x in range(0 , len(created)):
        
                        i.add(value[x])
```

You're adding every value to every printer.
What you want to do is add the values to each specific printer:

```
if len(created) == len(value):
    for i in range(len(created)):
        created[i].add(value[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Under your `if 'add' in command` statement, you can do the following such that you assign each printer its corresponding number/value:

```
        if 'add' in command:
            value = command.split(' ')
            value.remove(value[0])
            for printer, v in zip(created, value):  # Match printer objects with their corresponding values
                if len(created) == len(value):
                    printer.add(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use `enumerate()`

```
if 'add' in command:
    value = command.split(' ')
    value.remove(value[0])
         
    for x,i in enumerate(created):    
          i.add(int(value[x]))
```

Also, update your `range()`

```
if 'create' in command:
    val = command.split(' ')[1] #separation of command from value
    amount.append(val)
            
    for printers in range(1,int(val)+1):
        printers = Printer(printers)
        created.append(printers)
```

Here is sample:

```
#=== Input
create 5
add 1 3 2 4 5
status
#== Output
Printer: 1 Pages to print: 1 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 2 Pages to print: 3 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 3 Pages to print: 2 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 4 Pages to print: 4 Total pages printed: 0
Printer: 5 Pages to print: 5 Total pages printed: 0
```

It can also have any pages in any printer:

```
#== Input
create 10
add 1 5 3 2 6 7 8 4 9 10  
status
#== Output
Printer: 1 Pages to print: 1 Total pages printed: 0  
Printer: 2 Pages to print: 5 Total pages printed: 0  
Printer: 3 Pages to print: 3 Total pages printed: 0  
Printer: 4 Pages to print: 2 Total pages printed: 0  
Printer: 5 Pages to print: 6 Total pages printed: 0  
Printer: 6 Pages to print: 7 Total pages printed: 0  
Printer: 7 Pages to print: 8 Total pages printed: 0  
Printer: 8 Pages to print: 4 Total pages printed: 0  
Printer: 9 Pages to print: 9 Total pages printed: 0  
Printer: 10 Pages to print: 10 Total pages printed: 0
```